# Overlay video with transparency over another vide

Tags: android, video, transparency, textureview

I need to show(not to save) video with alpha channel over another normal video. I've tryed to layout one TextureView over another and stream videos from two media players, but it did not help because MadiaPlayer can't play video with transparency. I have mov format for transparent video.

Did someone solve the same problem?

Comment: I have the same problem, will update if I find a solution